# How to debug Yii REST controller file with xdebug and Netbeans (where to put breakpoint and what url use)?

Tags: netbeans, yii2, firebird, xdebug, yii-extensions

I have installed Netbenas, XAMPP, xdebug and Yii2 and I have simple REST controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class ContractController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Contract';
}
```

which connects to the Firebird 2.1 database (WIN1257) and gives error:

```
error on line 2 at column 431: Encoding error
```

I want to debug this error to determine how can I improve Yii-Firebird plugin but where can I put breakpoint if this controller has no action (action from base class is used). In run congfiguration I have Project URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/myproject/
```

and index file:

```
web/index.php
```

My intention was to put here url that gives error:

```
http://localhost:8081/myproject/web/index.php/contract
```

But Netbeans does not accept /contract part in index file field.

So - which file should I open in Netbenas and how to indicate that I want to debug url http://localhost:8081/myproject/web/index.php/contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
class ContractController extends ActiveController
```

is an extension of `ActiveController`

So you could place your breakpoint to the proper  ActiveController action ..

in

```
 vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/ActionController
```

you can find

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'index' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
        'create' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\CreateAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
            'scenario' => $this->createScenario,
        ],
        'update' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UpdateAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
            'scenario' => $this->updateScenario,
        ],
        'delete' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\DeleteAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

where you can see that for each action you have a proper class eg:..

```
  'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
```

In the same dir `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/ActionController`  you can find the class code

Then you could place the breakpoint on the related class run function

```
public function run()
{
    if ($this->checkAccess) {
        call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id);
    }

    return $this->prepareDataProvider();
}
```